# What "the hell" is this?

Tags: terminology

Take the following examples:

```
For the hell of it! 
How the hell...
What the hell...
Where the hell...
Who the hell...
The hell you are!
```

Is there any linguistic term with respect to `"the hell"`.

`"on earth"` and `"the heavens"` fall into the same category. Any others?

Comment: Obligatory reference: ["English sentences without overt grammatical subject"](http://lonniechu.com/QUANG.html)

Comment: Such expressions have been analyzed in terms of polarity. Try googling "polarity" and "the hell".

Comment: [Another reference linking 'the hell' to wh phenomena in Chinese.](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~ctjhuang/my_papers/2004.hell.pdf)

Comment: _The hell_ and related constructions [are covered here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pesetsky (1987, section 5.3.1 http://people.ucsc.edu/~ardeal/courses/synb-w12/pesetsky1987.pdf) addresses wh-phrases with "the hell" (and its ilk), and there's some bloggish discussion of it here: http://lingcomm.blogspot.com/2011/11/non-question-uses-of-hell.html

Per the discussion there, you might call such phrases "D-unlinkers" (but that would probably date you, and tie you to a particular framework/view of syntax, which may not be what you're looking for).